# Hyperledger fabric design architecture

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I have one use case for implementing private blockchain. I am considering using Hyperledger Fabric for implementing private blockchain.

**Use case**

As we know blockchain works with unknown parties which want to work together without any middle man. So, my use case is similar to this.
One organisation wants to deal with different vendors residing in different cities in the country which are not known to organisation. Now, we want to make smart contract according to our business logic between the organisation and vendors to do further transactions.

We will map our organisation to fabric organisation. But what to with vendors? As vendors are not separate organisation, they are individual entities.

I have worked for multi organisations with fabric but how should we make this architecture to work correctly where only one organisation is involved?

Comment: You can implement it in chaincodes as business logic. Think about how you would solve this problem in relational databases. You can implement similar logic in chaincode with composite keys etc.

Comment: Yes, I can do that. But I have question regarding architecture. I mean how much organisations I need to create? If I create organisation for each vendor then it will have separate peer and db also and it will require more server resources. What about CA? Do I need to create CA cluster with each org?